# Net::SMTPFatalError in MessagesController#create -- 550 Cannot receive from specified address : Unauthenticated senders not allowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sendgrid

I have a rails 4.1.8 app using Devise, Heroku and Sendgrid.  Sending emails is part of the apps functionality. Everything works perfectly in development on my laptop that I built the app in.  Emails are being sent and received...all is good.

I git cloned the repo on my desktop, and I am getting the above errors.

I have set up all of my ENV variables using the Figaro gem.  When I run `heroku config` on my dev laptop, all of the correct values and variables are present.

Here is my `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` file:

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.production?
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    address:        'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port:           '587',
    authentication: :plain,
    user_name:      ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    password:       ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    domain:         'heroku.com',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

I am using the Figaro gem, and have created a `config/application.yml` file on my dev laptop computer containing my secure ENV variables.  As this file is on the `.gitignore` list, I have also created an `config/application.yml` file in my desktop computer (the second computer) that looks like this:

```
SENDGRID_USERNAME:  <%= ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"] %>
SENDGRID_PASSWORD:  <%= ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"] %>

SECRET_KEY_BASE:    <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

DEVISE_SECRET_KEY:  <%= ENV["DEVISE_SECRET_KEY"] %>
```

Again, everything works perfectly in development on my dev laptop, but on my second computer I am getting this error:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError in MessagesController#create
550 Cannot receive from specified address <support@******.com>: Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing your `domain` to the domain that the email is originating from

Comment: Hello.  I tried that...no dice.  Same error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [SendGrid Gem](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/ruby.html)?

The `Unauthenticated senders not allowed` explicitly means that you're connecting to SendGrid, but are not attempting to make an `AUTH LOGIN` command before sending a message. I see you have the `authentication` defined, but something is keeping it from actually being enabled.

Comment: Hello.  I tried adding the `sendgrid` gem, added their `include SendGrid` statement in my `message_mailer.rb` file.  Still getting the same error.  Thanks.